# Visual Studio Code Typescript Intellisense stops working

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellisense, electron, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn how to build desktop application using Electron with the help of Typescript. Chose Visual Studio Code as the IDE. Everything went fine and I was able to load a sample html file in electron.

After working on Code for sometime, the intellisense for Typescript stops working and VS Code starts behaving strange.

I am no longer able to see intellisense for TS files, but the intellisense for JS files works perfectly fine, based on the reference tags added in it.

TSC compilation is working perfectly, as I am getting compilation errors on builds.

I copied the same project into a new folder, but now the intellisense seems to work perfectly for now.

There are no differences at all between the old project and new one.

Tried closing VS Code and opening it, machine restarts, re-installation of VS Code etc. Once it stops working in a project, it never gets fixed. TS intellisense is working on the new project, but not sure for how long.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Version details

npm -v
2.14.4

node -v
v4.1.2

tsc -v
1.6.2

Comment: Give this a go : https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript

Comment: @basarat Thanks, will look into it.. I ended up using Visual Studio 2015. No issues till now.

Answer (score 12):

Open up the command palette (CTRL+Shift+P) And select Reload Window. After that the typescript intellisense start working again.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with `tsserver`. atom-typescript avoids it by adding a "sync" button. VSCode should add that soon as well (F1 keyboard button).

See this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1342).